# How to replace leading spaces (only) with "&nbsp;" in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I’ve had this problem many times:
I have a piece of source code, but if I copy and paste it into Wordpress and enclose it with the `<code>...</code>` tags, the beginning spaces are “compressed” into one.

Thus I’d like to know how I could change all the spaces **only** at the beginning of the line by `&nbsp;`, so that, for example,

```
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
```

becomes

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
```

Comment: Use <pre><code>...</code></pre> instead of <code>...</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three approaches to implement the desired edit that I can
see, listed below in the order of my personal preference.

1. A substitution using the preceding-atom matching syntax
   (see `:help \@<=`):

   ```
    :%s/\%(^ *\)\@<= /\&nbsp;/g
   ```

   If brevity of the command is crucial, one can shorten it
   using the “very magic” mode (see `:help \v`) by changing
   the non-capturing group (`:help \%(`) to a capturing one:

   ```
    :%s/\v(^ *)@<= /\&nbsp;/g
   ```
2. A two-staged substitution that splits a line just after the leading
   spaces, replaces those spaces, and rejoins that line:

   ```
    :g/^/s/^ \+/&\r/|-s/ /\&nbsp;/g|j!
   ```
3. Another two-step substitution that replaces each of the leading
   spaces by certain symbol that does not occur in the text, and changes
   that symbol to `&nbsp;`:

   ```
    :exe "g/^ \\+/norm!v//e\rr\r" | %s/\r/\&nbsp;/g
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for the answers, this is incredibly useful. I'm going to spend some time reading vim help. Time, time, ime!!

Answer (score 4):

```
:%s/^ \+/\=repeat("&nbsp;",strlen(submatch(0)))
```

But it wouldn't surprise me if there's a shorter substitute command. Come on Vimgolfers!

Comment: This is the most comprehensive solution (to me), and I've checked the ib's answer because of the useful help tips. Thanks again for answering so quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Using a look-behind assertion to replace spaces precedeed by only spaces at the beginning of a line:

```
%s/\(^ *\)\@<= /\&nbsp;/g
```

Comment: Huh, it is funny coincidence of thought process!  I did not notice your answer and have proposed almost the same solution.  By the way, it is not necessary to use capturing group, `\(`.

Comment: It does make it a character shorter, though. :)

Comment: Okay, I can make the pattern even shorter: `:%s/\v(^ *)@<= /\&nbsp;/g`  :-)