# how to exactily repeat the n matched pattern in result string

Tags: regex, vim

How to exactly repeat the n matched pattern in result string?

Example if I have the folowing text:

```
++ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
++ . /etc/bashrc
+++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
+++ '[' -z 'printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"' ']'
+++ shopt -s checkwinsize
+++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' = '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
+++ shopt -q login_shell
+++ '[' 506 -gt 199 ']'
++++ id -gn
```

Now I want to substitute every '+' for 3 spaces, but it can only happen at the begining of the pattern. I would use `:<range>s/^<pattern>` `:%s/+/   /g`, but if it there were a '+' in the rest of the text I would simply mess it up.

The question:
How to match every + at begining and repeat the same count of found + in the result string?
expected:

```
^   ++$  -> ^         $
^   +++$ -> ^            $
^   +$   -> ^      $
```

Thanks

Comment: See also the question "[Vim regexp help: change spaces to “&nbsp;”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6879425/254635)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/^+*/\=repeat('   ',strlen(submatch(0)))/
```

`submatch(0)` contains all the matched `+` at the start of the line, `strlen` counts them. So for every plus sign at the start of the line three spaces are inserted using `repeat`.

For more information:

```
:help sub-replace-expression
:help repeat()
:help submatch()
:help strlen()
```

Answer (score 3):

An elegant substitution command for this case is the following:

```
:%s/\%(^+*\)\@<=+/   /g
```

Comment: @ib. can you explain your expression a little bit?

Comment: `\(an\_s\+\)\@<=file`  "file" after "an" and white space or an end-of-line (from vim `:help \@<=` ) \%( \) make the inside content be an atom.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to run an expression several times, if that is acceptable...

You'll want to run something like this (minus the single quotes, which are used to show whitespace):

```
'^(\s*)+'
```

replacing with something like (again minus the single quotes)

```
'$1   '
```

Not every problem that can be solved with regular expressions can be solved using only a single regular expression - I'm pretty sure this is one of those cases

This expression/replacement pair will need to be run once for each plus sign at the beginning of the line with the most plus signs (in your example above, that would be four times) N.B.: as written, this will mess up any lines that are supposed to begin with whitespace and plus signs , so I hope that doesn't happen anywhere...

Comment: that's the way I do now =D, `%s:^\(\s*\)+:\1   /g`, but then I must execute n times until nothing is matched

Comment: Though I'm not incredibly familiar with the regex syntax you're using there, I'm pretty sure there are at least two differences. First, I use the beginning of line anchor `^`, which ensures you won't match plus signs in the "middle" of the string. Second, I repeat the whitespace _any number of times_ (then store it in the first backreference, and inject into the replacement expression, as you did) - please feel free to correct me :-D ..... ... ... okay, now you've changed it to include the differences I mentioned (????)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the functions that seem to be able to be injected, like @dusan used, so that may be closer to what you are looking for